# Ruby on rails 5 validation fails with belongs to with relation being present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 different associations to the same table, as defined like below in my model (Grant):

```
belongs_to :taxes_period, class_name: 'Period'
belongs_to :insurance_period, class_name: 'Period'
```

Period is a table that has values `Monthly`, `Quarterly`, `Yearly`. So in my grant form update or create, I get validation error on the back-end (`@grant.errors`) :

```
 @details={:taxes_period=>[{:error=>:blank}]},
 @messages={:taxes_period=>["must exist"]}>
```

But when I inspect the object for presence of `taxes_period_id`, it's in there, putting relevant debugging details:

```
@grant.taxes_period_id
=> 2
[7] pry(#<GrantsController>)> Period.find(@grant.taxes_period_id)
  Period Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "periods".* FROM "periods" WHERE "periods"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Period:0x007f8571220e18 id: 2, name: "Monthly">
[8] pry(#<GrantsController>)> @grant.valid?
  Period Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "periods".* FROM "periods" ORDER BY "periods"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Period Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "periods".* FROM "periods" WHERE "periods"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> false
```

Why am I unable to save this object? What is going on here?

Comment: You put `rails 5` in the title, and `rails 4` as a tag. Which is it? Please correct.

Comment: Is this in the context of a test? Is it possibly you're dealing with a stale object and are therefore seeing misleading data? Try: `@grant.reload.taxes_period_id`

Comment: @TomLord just corrected incorrect tagging. I can't reload because the update is failing, if I reload old object will reloaded. But here is an interesting fact is that I've saved an object with `taxes_period_id=2` doing with `validate(false)` and when I pulled it in the `rails console` the `. taxes_period` comes back as nil even though `taxes_period_id` and `reload.taxes_period_id` comes back as 2

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Have you defined a `taxes_period` method on the model? Are you stubbing something in the test? What does the whole test look like? Are there any `before_create` etc hooks that could be impacting things?

Comment: hi @TomLord yes I have it on my model defined like this `belongs_to :taxes_period, class_name: 'Period'`, I also have presence validation for `taxes_period`. This is not only in the test, this is in the actual app, I am unable to update or save my objects because of this, not passing validation

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47035892/edit) and **show all the relevant code**. People reading this will not want to dig through the comments to find crucial bits of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer short, the relation name is incorrect, it should have been named :

`tax_period_id` instead of `taxes_period_id`

There wasn't anymore to that, I guess rails does enforce convention over configuration. Everything starts from proper naming I guess, was really a last resort that worked.